# change browser tab title for community

Tags: visualforce

So I know in the 
`<apex:page title="My Tab Title">`
 tag I can add a title and it changes the tab title. The problem is it appends the community name to the title I set creating something like

```
My Tab Title ~ community name
```

as my tab title. We do not want the community name to display after the tab title is there a way to suppress that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the title using javascript

```
document.title = "This is the new page title.";
```

This will solve the issue.

Note: Not supported by SEO.

Comment: super easy. I should've thought of that. thanks Tushar.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma - is there any way to change the title conditionally

Comment: @SupriyaKale yes pass title as dynamic string or use JS to conditionally set it.